# Yocto morty build to emmc

Tags: yocto, intel

I have created a Yocto build for my Kontron mal10. It works correctly, and I can flash my USB stick with the HDDIMG image using Win32DiskManager. The board then boots in live mode.

However, when I try to use `dd` to copy the HDDIMG image to my internal eMMC storage (/dev/mmcblk1), there is no boot option to boot from eMMC after the process is complete.

Here is my `fdisk -l` output from the eMMC:

`root@mal1-64:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 15.0 GB, 15023996928 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 458496 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

```
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
```

/dev/mmcblk1p1   ?    50382796    57146407   216435558+  7 HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/mmcblk1p2   ?    51125328    14539277   976730017  16 Hidden FAT16
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/mmcblk1p3   ?           1           1           0  6f Unknown
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/mmcblk1p4          784385    15227131   462167897   0 Empty
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary
`
Is my approach correct? The option to install the image when I boot from USB does not appear.

Thanks,

what i try is also in part one explained.